# Python code that will automatically reset master bone of an IK rig?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, add-on

The title might be a bit confusing, but basically I have a typical IK rig setup. However, there are only IK legs. So I have 2 IK leg bones, and the hip bone to move the body over top.

When animating with IK feet, the master bone tends to get left behind. So what I want to do is make a script/python add on that will automatically do this:[image: i]

To explain, here is what happens:
 1. Move the 3 IK bones back on top of the master bone
 2. Move the master bone forward to where the character was

So yeah it sounds simple but I can't seem to figure out what commands to use to do this. Since its not the same distance always.

Thanks for any help.